# How to know when grub memtest is complete

Tags: memtest

I have a test that has been running for over eight hours. There is a message to press Esc to exit, but it is still running.

It shows 0 errors so far.

Will it eventually stop? How do I know that the test has been completed.

My journal shows an error about Memory Corruption but the system is working without issue, so I'm confused about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MemTest will keep running forever until you stop it. This allows you to run long-term tests which might discover issues that only show up after some time.

It has a **Pass** counter which increments every time it starts again from the beginning when the full set of test algorithms has completed:

[image: MemTest screenshot with Pass count highlighted]

Generally, [they say a single pass should usually be enough](https://www.memtest86.com/technical.htm#execution) but if you have reason to suspect any defects, more passes might detect some more obscure problems.

Comment: So I could let it run longer. It is possible that the error in the journal is a software glitch? Given that it is so frequently and quickly reported it would likely show up within a single pass of the memtest. Is that a fair interpretation?

Comment: I doubt it's a hardware RAM defect if it isn't detected by few passes of MemTest yet occurs frequently during normal operation. You'd have to ask a new question and include the actual, full error messages from your syslog though to get help interpreting them and finding their cause and hopefully a fix.